# Remote PostgreSQL connections don't work with proper listen address and pg_hba line

Tags: postgresql

This is something I've done several times without issue, but for some reason I'm unable to connect to a remote PostgreSQL server.

My server is Debian 10 with PostgreSQL 11 installed from the repositories, and the TimescaleDB extensions added. Otherwise nothing special.

`/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf` contains the line `listen_addresses='*'`, and `/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf` contains

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

I've left everything wide open just to be able to connect, and I can verify that the local login works using `psql -U postgres -h localhost` but when I try the same remotely I get

```
psql: could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "db.example.com" (10.0.0.150) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The server is listening from what I see using `ss`

```
$ ss -anp | grep 5432
u_str LISTEN 0      128           /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 158425                                                * 0                                                                                                                   
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                                     0.0.0.0:5432                                            0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                                        [::]:5432                                               [::]:*
```

and I've temporarily disabled the firewall to troubleshoot. Other services (SSH) work as expected, so I'm really not sure why this one isn't. The only thing I'm not sure of is that this host is using an IP that was previously assigned to one that no longer exists, but DNS reports back the same IP for two different names. I would think that using the IP address directly with `psql` would ignore this, but I get the same error.

Lastly I ran `tcpdump` on the server and it sees the connection request

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i ens192 -vvvnxXS port 5432
tcpdump: listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:27:46.118205 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18195, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.0.2.3.59478 > 10.0.0.150.5432: Flags [S], cksum 0xea81 (correct), seq 826121699, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2129657941 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 4713 4000 4006 dd10 0a00 0203  E..<G.@.@.......
    0x0010:  0a00 0096 e856 1538 313d 9de3 0000 0000  .....V.81=......
    0x0020:  a002 faf0 ea81 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ................
    0x0030:  7ef0 0055 0000 0000 0103 0307            ~..U........
```

but the client side sees nothing.

I'm wondering if this is a routing issue somewhere between the two, but I really don't see how because running `mtr` against the IP address gives a result with a single hop. Also, I've tried connecting from a virtual machine that resides on the same set of virtual hosts that share a switch.

Comment: Just poiniting a few basic things out: you've restarted postgres right? Also, are you sure there is no other firewall in between, one that your provider provides you for example?

Comment: I have indeed restarted postgres after changing the configs. There isn't another firewall in the way as far as I'm aware, I've been in contact with my network admin and there shouldn't be. It's suspect though that I'd be able to SSH but not hit the database service.

Comment: I've just tried myself by installed postgresql 11 in ubuntu 18.04 and wasn't even able to connect through ssh tunnel. Perhaps this is related to your issue. I can't provide a solution though. I tried many things

Comment: Nah, it's not an issue with postgresql 11, I set up a server the exact same way at home a couple of days ago and had no issues. I'm actually using the identical configuration here as I have there.

Comment: Which provider are you hosting your server at?

Comment: I'm not, it's a VM hosted by the company I work for.

Comment: The _No route to host_ part of the error message is generated by the network stack of the client, and normally leaves no doubt about this being a TCP/IP routing issue totally outside of PostgreSQL control or configuration.

Comment: Also check if your port forwarding is set up correctly. Even if you disabled the firewall, that doesn't mean a direct connection to postgres would work

Answer (score 1):

This issue was indeed routing related and was caused by reusing the DNS reservation. When my IT department changed the IP address of the server it started to work.